# set Select All as initial value in ng-dropdown-multiselect

Tags: angularjs

I have the following angular js code in the view

```
<div class="icon-dropdown people-icon fixed-height-select" ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="vm.collectionGroups" selected-model="vm.selectedCollections" ng-click="vm.events.getStatistics()"></div>
```

and i would like to programatically set the "Select All" option as initially selected option.

Comment: Is that a plugin? can you tag/link to it?

Comment: Um can you provide a working sample of your code?

Comment: @user2899925 i had not tried it but can you check by keeping same array data in `vm.collectionGroups` and `vm.selectedCollections`, i am checking if the `vm.selectedCollections` has data by default it should be made it as selected by default.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an option or function on the directive that can achieve the `Select All` behaviour.

What you can do is to initialize in you controller your `vm.selectedCollections`.

```
this.selectedCollections = this.collectionGroups.map(function(item) {
  return { id : item.id };
});
```

which create a collection like `[{id:1}, {id:2}, .. ];`

For more info, you can see the [documentation](http://dotansimha.github.io/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/#/) at the *Pre-selected Values* section.

Comment: i was just asking if i could fire the selectAll event of the "Check All" option that is present in the ng-dropdown-multiselect, if i don't disable it using showCheckAll = false

Comment: Oh ok.. so as I looked at the documentation and implementation of the directive, I don't see how you can call the `selectAll` method on the directive without modifying the plugin's code

Comment: yeah, unfortunatelly me neither

Answer (score 0):

ng-dropdown-multiselect has preselect value and it is working with id.

so your preselect value which is vm.selectedColletions has to be id inside it.

so it should be

```
// list selected id
this.selectedCollections = [
  {
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 3
  }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just initialize it to

```
this.example1model = [
    {id: 1, label: "xx"},
    {id: 2, label: "yy"},
    {id: 3, label: "zz"}
];
```

where example1model is selected-model which would select all by default

Answer (score 0):

Your Javascript should be like this:

```
function(){
  $scope.vm.selectedCollections = angular.copy($scope.vm.collectionGroups);
};
```

selected-model = options . :) Easy.

Answer (score 0):

After **giving lot of try,** I found simple **solution** as below

```
self.example1model = data;
self.selectedCollections = data.slice(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

your options may be like below,

```
$scope.vm.collectionGroups=[
{"id": 0, "label": "Colum-0", "group": "group-1"},
{"id": 1, "label": "Colum-1", "group": "group-1"},
{"id": 2, "label": "Colum-2", "group": "group-2"},
{"id": 3, "label": "Colum-3", "group": "group-2"}
];
```

you can initialize your model using spread operator like this,

```
$scope.vm.selectedCollections= [...$scope.vm.collectionGroups];
```